# How to send a pdf save on s3 as attachment using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, nodemailer

I have a function to send an email with a pdf attach, but when I try send a pdf that no has file locally, the email arrive without any attachment...

```
async sendEmailWithAtt(email, subject, message, pathAtt) {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
        },
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'Document',
                path: pathAtt, // URL of document save in the cloud.
                contentType: 'application/pdf'
            }
        ]
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        text: message
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nodemailer [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/) states that if you want to use an URL, you have to use `href` instead of `path` which is reserved for local files.

If the file is not publicly available, you can pass some headers using `httpHeaders` property.

```
attachments: [
 {
     filename: 'Document',
     href: pathAtt, // URL of document save in the cloud.
     contentType: 'application/pdf'
  }
]
```

Aside from that, you're setting `attachments` in `.createTransport` you should put it inside the message instead.

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    text: message,
    attachments: [ /* ... */]
};

await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm using Gmail, I need to allow something there?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Is the url publicly available?

Comment: Open the URL you're putting in the `href` in the browser, can you see the file?

Comment: Yes, if i  put the url on browser the file open, but when I send the email arrive without any attachment :(

Comment: Check updated answer, you're using `attachment` in the wrong object.

Answer (score -1):

```
 function sendFile(){    

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: '',//put email_host
        port: '', // put port 
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: '',//put user email
            pass: '' //put password
        }
    });

    

    let mailToUser = {
        from: 'demo@gmail.com', //replace with user_email
        to: 'test@gmail.com', // replace with that want to send it
        
        html: "Hello",
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: `test.pdf`
                path :`` //put S3 url
                
                
            }
        ]

    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailToUser, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
             console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info);
    });
}
```